# Consulta para mostrar solo campos que no esten vacios!

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con 20 campos los cuales se van rellenando por un for y la cantidad de datos que yo le diga que inserte. Pero ahora necesito mostrar los datos de cada fila, pero que me muestre nada mas los campos que tengan datos, o sea que los que esten vacios no me los muestre. Como podria ser la consulta SQL. Aqui tengo la fila de mi tabla, en este caso quiero mostrar solo los 8 campos que tengo rellenos, obviando los que esten vacios. En cuanto a codigo, lo que no se plantear es la sentencia SQL para obviar los campos vacios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luis, por favor ayúdanos con el código de tu consulta, las tablas, necesitamos más información para poder entender tu problema y poderte ayudar.

Comment: Como dije Stalin necesito mostrar solo los campos  que esten llenos, obviar los vacios. Deje la imagen de la fila de mi tabla. Solo quiero mostrar esos 8 campos llenos, y obviar los que esten vacios. Estoy perdido es en la sentencia SQL para hacer eso. O no se si se pueda realizar a traves de PHP.

Comment: No entiendo bien claramente que necesitas hacer, te recomiendo que coloques la sentencia sql que tienes, pero según puedo ver no quieres que salga en su sentencia los últimos 8 campos para eso simplemente no lo coloque en el select de tu consulta:  select id, id_canidad, costo0, costo1 from tabla.

Comment: Primero deberías [normalizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) tu tabla (y tu base de datos) para tener un mejor diseño, evitar la redundacia de información, facilitar las consultas, mantener la integridad, etc. En este caso no estás cumpliendo la Primera Forma Normal creando [grupos repetidos a través de columnas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primera_forma_normal#Ejemplo_2:_Grupos_repetidos_a_trav.C3.A9s_de_columnas)

Comment: Stalin explico mejor, tengo unos cursos los cuales se rigen por cuotas de pago que pueden ir de 1-15 cuotas. Entonces cuando yo vaya a consultar un curso para ver sus cuotas, debo mostrar solo las cuotas pertenecientes a ese curso, pero obviamente debo mostrar nada mas los campos que tengan datos. Por ej: Curso 1 tiene 8 cuotas, los montos son: aqui tendria que mostrar los 8 campos esos que te mencione. Pero no solo tengo esa fila, hay muchas y algunas estan mas llenas que otras. Por eso debo mostrar solo los campos que esten llenos.

Comment: Eso he pensado Matias, que no deberia tener tantos campos en mi tabla, pero de verdad no se de que forma podria hacer, porque debo guardar todos los montos de cada cuota. Que opcion me puedes dar respecto a eso.

Comment: @LuisHenriquez Podes crear una nueva tabla Cuotas con los campos id_cuota, costo y una clave foránea que dependa de la tabla que tenes ahora. Igual te recomiendo que leas sobre normalización de base de datos.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo de lo que propones matias es ese campo costo. Que va a guardarse en ese campo. Si ya los costos los tengo en la tabla que muestro.

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberías replantear tu diseño de base de datos, pues si existiera un tipo de crédito de por ejemplo 50 cuotas tendrias 50 columnas y para otro cliente de 9 cuotas tendrias solo 9 columnas y 41 columnas vacias, esto con el tiempo te traera problemas ademas de que no estas contemplando el tema de Normalizacion de BD.

Te dejo de un pequeño de ejemplo de como deberia estar relacionado el tema de cuotas y asi no tendras campos vacios. Te dejo el link del ejemplo http://rextester.com/MEQOE3924

Por ejemplo para obtener las cuotas del id "3" seria mas o menos lo siguiente:

```
select * from detalle_cuotas where cantidad_id = '3';
```

Comment: Ademas esta claro que en tus consultas deberia no usar Select * from table

Comment: Entendi bien el ejemplo que me pasaste, ya se me aclara un poco mas el panorama. Lo que me esta liando la vida es que cada 3 cuotas el monto debe aumentarse un 20%. Eso me tiene echo un lio Alan.

Comment: Pero eso lo controlas al momento de realizar el insert creo que eso lo resolviste en otra pregunta , esta vez sí tienes 9 cuotas deberás realizar 9 insert y ahí vas calculando el tema del 20 %.